# Virtualize native Fedora on Windows 10 with EFI

Tags: linux, virtualbox, uefi

I have a Windows 10 and Fedora 26 dual boot on my laptop. I have created a rawvmdk using vboxmangage commands to use the raw partitions required for Fedora, including the EFI partition.

When mounted in VirtualBox, I am able to get the startup screen of Fedora, and the boot proceeds until some point were I get I/O errors for sda1.

[image: VirtualBox Screenshot of I/O error]

If I use a different vdi and mount the `/home` from the raw disk, it works fine. Please help create a way to boot the EFI Fedora 26 installed. I hate Windows 10, but I need to use it due to some missing drivers for Fedora/Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue was having amdgpu drivers to be used by force through the /etc/X11/xorg  files.
Removed that and boot went through! I can finally have both windows and linux running native!